# InitBinder for method

Tags: java, spring, validation

I have a rest controller:

```
@RestController
public abstract class CrudController {

    @RequestMapping(
        path = "delete",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO<Void>> delete(
        @RequestBody IdDTO request,
        @RequestHeader("X-auth-token") String token,
        BindingResult bindingResult
    ) {
        //delete logic            
    }

    @RequestMapping(
        path = "read",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO<DTO>> read(
        @RequestBody IdDTO<User> request,
        @RequestHeader("X-auth-token") String token,
        BindingResult bindingResult
    ) {
        //read logic
    }
}
```

I wanted to add Spring Validation. It is obvious that for read method and for delete method should be different validators. I want to know it it possible to make two @InitBinder one for read and another for delete?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're not quite familiar with usage of BindingResult. It is used in process of binding object from request to Java object.
It searches the class validator, or uses validation annotations used on class' fields. Object you want to bind needs to be annotated with @Valid.

For example:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Note> addNote(@Valid Note note, BindingResult result) {
   if(result.hasErrors())
      return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();

   noteService.save(note);
   return ResponseEntity.ok(noteService.getNoteById(note.getId()));
}
```

What you're trying to do is validate something, but not quite bind it.

I also suggest using different http methods for delete and read(GET) in the same path rather than POST method in different paths.

Comment: First of all, if you don't add `@InitBinder` with `webDataBinder.setValidator(validator);` or `webDataBinder.addValidator(validator);` `@Valid` will trigger only JSR-303 validation. To trigger Spring Validation you need to `@InitBinder` method. Secondly, it is possible to autowire my validators into controller and trigger validation manually, but I have to manually handle errors in that case. I would like to avoid it.